# How do I retain a mutable number?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I built a data system comprised of many multidimensional arrays which are accessed by an index which I store, but can change by the user. I naively presumed NSNumber could be modified but that is clearly not its purpose, so I'm a bit stuck. I cannot retain ints at all, as I lose them when I segue across views.

There's got to be a simple way of storing persistent ints but my investigations have left me a bit worried. Wat do?

The way my system works is straight forward is apt to:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *data;
@property NSInteger *index; // this needs to be persistent across views

...

int index = *(_dataStorage.index);
NSSomeObject something;
[_dataStorage.data replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:something];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSInteger *index;` - Why? Why not `NSInteger index`? And why do you need to retain it? If you have an index, make that a read-write property, and whoever uses your object will be able to write

```
theObject.index = newIndex;
```

Comment: I suppose I don't need a pointer. Good call - Habit.

By default isn't my NSInteger already read/write?

The index can de/increment at the push of a button by the user from multiple views, and the displayed data is dependent on the index so tracking it is essential.

Comment: @JesseMeyer That's what `@property (assign) NSInteger index;` is called. What's the problem with tracking?

Comment: Actually, your suggestion seems to have either fixed my problem or I'm suffering a different problem than I had originally thought. Thanks!